# Reverse a singly linked list recursively by dividing linked list in half in each recurrence

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

How can I write a function in java that reverse a singly linked list by dividing it into half that means (n/2) nodes for first part and rest is second Part (n is size of the liked list) until it reaches one Node and then merge this divided parts. Using two new Linked list is allowed in each divide but using list Node is not. The function must be **void** and there are **no parameters** for the function. I have **n, head and tail** of main Linked list.

I found this code on websites but it doesn't divide Linked list into half, so it is not helpful.

```
static ListNode reverseR(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    ListNode first = head;
    ListNode rest = head.next;

    // reverse the rest of the list recursively
    head = reverseR(rest);

    // fix the first node after recursion
    first.next.next = first;
    first.next = null;

    return head;
}
```

Comment: That seems really inefficient, do you have an actual use for it or is it just an excercise?

Comment: This is just an excercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're working with a linked list, the approach you suggest is unlikely to be efficient. Ascertaining where the midpoint lies is a linear time operation, and even if the size of the list was known, you would still have to iterate up to the midpoint. Because you have a linear term at each node of the recurrence tree, the overall performance will be O(n lg n), slower than the O(n) bound for the code which you have provided.

That being said, you could still reverse the list by the following strategy:

```
 Step 1: Split the list L into A (the first half) and B (the second half).
 Step 2: Recurse on each of A and B. This recursion should bottom out 
         when given a list of length 1.
 Step 3: Attach the new head of the reversed A to the new tail of the reversed B.
```

You can see that to begin with, our list is AB. We then recurse to get A' and B', each the reversed version of the half lists. We then output our new reversed list B'A'. The first element of the original A is now the last element of the list overall, and the last element of the original B is now the first overall.

Comment: the problem is that, there is no parameters for function for passing new lists recursively.

Comment: Presumably your function is allowed to take the list as a parameter? How else will it reverse the list?